# Disable 'Download a copy' option in ribbon

Tags: subfolders

I can hide 'disable a copy' option using css. 
but it disables at complete page.

Is it possible to Disable 'Download a copy' option at FOLDER level(sub folder) in document library?  (because even i give permission as view only to the user, he is able to see download a copy option and able to download).
How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to assign the users the "View only" permission for that folder

Comment: but still it will show the 'download a copy' in ribbon

Comment: It should be dimmed out for office docs. Is it PDF docs you are using?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. Yes, I'm using Pdf docs.

Comment: Then that approach will not work . https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your reply :)